# How to setup public key for verifying JWT tokens from Keycloak?

Tags: jwt, rsa, keycloak

I'm writing backend microservice that receives requests from front-end which have `Authorisation: Bearer ...` header, with token obtained from keycloak (which is inside docker container).

I got the RSA public key to verify the signature of that token from Keys section of realm settings, but it seems that when container with keycloak restarts, it regenerates pair of keys, and my public key set in service config becomes invalid.

What is the proper way to work with RSA public key from keycloak? Is there some way to configure it to use a fixed pair of keys for realm? Are keys exported when realm exports? Or I have to get the public key from keycloak using url like `http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/:realm_name:`, which I rather not to do because this adds a dependency between keycloak and backend.

Comment: public key for realm remains same after restarts, it changes when you reinitialise keycloak.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that it is inside docker container, so probably it also reinitializes when container is recreated from image.

Comment: Keys are different with initialization, you can write a initialisation script (with steps to be performed) and call from Dockerfile

Answer (score 11):

You should verify the JWT token's signature based on the issuer identity server's `/.well-known/jwks` endpoint.

1) Query the issuer identity server's `/.well-known/jwks` endpoint (JWKS stands for JSON Web Key Set)

2) From the JWKS, get the JWK (JSON Web Key) with the same `kid` (Key ID) as the `Bearer` token we are verifying. To get the `kid` from your JWT token, first decode it using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)'s Debugger tool.

3) As long as identity server-issued tokens are verified with an asymmetric cryptography algorithm (e.g.: RS256), we can verify the signature with the Public Key only (so you won't need the Private Key)

4) The Public Key can be retrieved from the JWK (it is the `x5c` entry in the JWK JSON )

5) Verify the JWT `Bearer` token's signature with this Public Key.

For example, in Java you can verify it like this:

```java
// verify JWT signature based on Access Identity's JWKS RSA public key (RS256)
try {

  Jwk jwk = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL(issuer + Constants.JWKS_ENDPOINT)).get(decodedJWT.getKeyId());
  final PublicKey publicKey = jwk.getPublicKey();

  if (!(publicKey instanceof RSAPublicKey)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key with ID " + decodedJWT.getKeyId() + " was found in JWKS but is not a RSA-key.");
  }

  Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) publicKey, null);
  JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
      .withIssuer(issuer)
      .build(); //Reusable verifier instance

  verifier.verify(bearerToken);

  LOGGER.info("Token verified!");

} catch (Exception e) {
  LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
  throw new InvalidAccessTokenException("JWTVerificationException - Invalid token signature.");
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/.well-known/jwks` and `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/.well-known/jwks.json` are both a 404 on a keycloak server. (It should have the `.json` extension, right?)

Comment: However, `new UrlJwkProvider(new URL("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs"))` works. Google also doesn't have a `.well-known/jwks` - so I don't know how "well-known" that is...

Comment: They both have a `.well-known/openid-configuration` though. That will return an object that contains a `jwks_url` field. For Keycloak, the jwks url will be `/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs"`

Comment: Guess it's not so well known huh. "#RedHat"